# How to open Tkinter GUI on second monitor/display? (Windows)

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, tk-toolkit

I'd like to incorporate a way to have my GUI open on a second monitor, if available. I want to add in some type of error handling so if there is a second monitor, use it, else open on the center of the detected display. Can this be done?

Comment: There is a module [screeninfo](https://github.com/rr-/screeninfo) can be used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On MacOS, use `Appkit`:

```
import AppKit

[(screen.frame().size.width, screen.frame().size.height)
    for screen in AppKit.NSScreen.screens()]
```

will give you a list of tuples containing all screen sizes (if multiple monitors present)

Comment: Awesome, thank you. The solution provided above for Windows seems much more intensive, is there also a simpler solution like this for Windows that you are aware of?

Comment: [this](https://pypi.org/project/screeninfo/), maybe?

Answer (score 12):

I've been using this snippet using the win32 API to enumerate monitors on windows:

```
import ctypes
user = ctypes.windll.user32

class RECT(ctypes.Structure):
  _fields_ = [
    ('left', ctypes.c_long),
    ('top', ctypes.c_long),
    ('right', ctypes.c_long),
    ('bottom', ctypes.c_long)
    ]
  def dump(self):
    return [int(val) for val in (self.left, self.top, self.right, self.bottom)]

class MONITORINFO(ctypes.Structure):
  _fields_ = [
    ('cbSize', ctypes.c_ulong),
    ('rcMonitor', RECT),
    ('rcWork', RECT),
    ('dwFlags', ctypes.c_ulong)
    ]

def get_monitors():
  retval = []
  CBFUNC = ctypes.WINFUNCTYPE(ctypes.c_int, ctypes.c_ulong, ctypes.c_ulong, ctypes.POINTER(RECT), ctypes.c_double)
  def cb(hMonitor, hdcMonitor, lprcMonitor, dwData):
    r = lprcMonitor.contents
    #print("cb: %s %s %s %s %s %s %s %s" % (hMonitor, type(hMonitor), hdcMonitor, type(hdcMonitor), lprcMonitor, type(lprcMonitor), dwData, type(dwData)))
    data = [hMonitor]
    data.append(r.dump())
    retval.append(data)
    return 1
  cbfunc = CBFUNC(cb)
  temp = user.EnumDisplayMonitors(0, 0, cbfunc, 0)
  #print(temp)
  return retval

def monitor_areas():
  retval = []
  monitors = get_monitors()
  for hMonitor, extents in monitors:
    data = [hMonitor]
    mi = MONITORINFO()
    mi.cbSize = ctypes.sizeof(MONITORINFO)
    mi.rcMonitor = RECT()
    mi.rcWork = RECT()
    res = user.GetMonitorInfoA(hMonitor, ctypes.byref(mi))
    data = mi.rcMonitor.dump()
#    data.append(mi.rcWork.dump())
    retval.append(data)
  return retval


if __name__ == "__main__":
  print(monitor_areas())
```

On my system that prints
[[0, 0, 3440, 1440], [3440, 0, 5120, 1050]]

In tkinter you can then move your app window to a given location with

```
appwindow.geometry('+1720+720')
```

Which puts it 1720px in from the left and 720 down from the top.

Any monitors that are to the left of or above your primary monitor may get negative coordinates, but they should work just fine.

Comment: Thank you so much for the help. I imported this into my code and it's working - my console is printing the dimensions of both of my displays: [[0, 0, 1920, 1080], [1920, 0, 3840, 1080]]

I have a question about passing the monitor_areas array into the appwindow.geometry. Can you provide some insight on how I can create something like this? 

If the monitor_areas array length is greater than 4 (more than one monitor), then use the largest display connected (I will assume the person using my program wants it on that monitor) and pass those dimensions to the appwindow.geometry?