# How to have a maximized window and disable resizing without overlay the taskbar on Windows - tkinter / tk-toolkit

Tags: python, windows, tkinter, winapi, tk-toolkit

I write an app in python, using Tkinter. I want it to be zoomed and not resizable, but when i do this, it hides the taskbar, which I want to keep. Is there any way with that can be done?

```
from tkinter import *

root=Tk()
root.state('zoomed')
root.resizable(False, False)
```

Python 3.8
Windows 10

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Please include a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: When you say "taskbar", are you talking about the taskbar of a particular OS?

Answer (score 2):

Tkinter just makes calls to the operating system in this case and this is how Windows reacts to this composition of states. The related source code can be found here:

[Changing state](https://github.com/tcltk/tk/blob/main/win/tkWinEmbed.c#L734) and the [implementation details](https://github.com/tcltk/tk/blob/main/win/tkWinWm.c#L2115).

To achieve what you want you can use ctypes and retrieve the work area of the current monitor. Better use `win32api` for this task, but for the proof of concept:

```
import tkinter as tk
import ctypes

user32 = ctypes.WinDLL('user32')
MONITOR_DEFAULTTONEAREST = 0x00000002

class RECT(ctypes.Structure):
    _fields_ = [
        ('left', ctypes.c_long),
        ('top', ctypes.c_long),
        ('right', ctypes.c_long),
        ('bottom', ctypes.c_long)
        ]
    def dump(self):
        return [int(val) for val in (
            self.left, self.top, self.right, self.bottom)]

class MONITORINFO(ctypes.Structure):
    _fields_ = [
        ('cbSize', ctypes.c_ulong),
        ('rcMonitor', RECT),
        ('rcWork', RECT),
        ('dwFlags', ctypes.c_ulong)
        ]

def maximize(window):
    hWnd = int(window.wm_frame(),16)
    mi = MONITORINFO()
    mi.cbSize = ctypes.sizeof(MONITORINFO)
    mi.rcMonitor = RECT()
    mi.rcWork = RECT()
    hMonitor = user32.MonitorFromWindow(hWnd,MONITOR_DEFAULTTONEAREST)
    result = user32.GetMonitorInfoA(hMonitor, ctypes.byref(mi))
    x,y,w,h = mi.rcWork.dump()
    window.geometry(f'{w}x{h}+-10+0')

root = tk.Tk()
maximize(root)
root.resizable(False, False)
root.mainloop()
```

Tested with Python 3.11 and tkinter 3.6.12 on Windows 11

Note this was created with the help of this [example](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65256092/13629335)

Answer (score 0):

I have found a work around but it is far from perfect.
After importing Tk, and creating a window, Start by setting the window to full screen size, and then used zoomed for actual full screen. Don't worry about adding the resizable as false, leave that out.

```
root.geometry("1920x1080") # Set the size to full screen.
root.state('zoomed') # Now used zoomed state to get actual full screen.
```

```
def stop_resize(event):
       if self.state() == "zoomed":
           pass
       else:
           self.state('zoomed')
        
self.bind("<Configure>", stop_resize)
```

Finnaly, you can bind a function to the window resize event which will set it to full screen if someone presses the button to make it smaller. (the maximize button next to the red X) In this case, the window is moveable but not resizable.